# Duplicating SOF questions on other resources

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274865/jpopupmenu-disappears-on-mouseentered) the question on `SOF` and, as I didn't got an answer, I've decided to repeat my search in google, and I've found a several sites which duplicate the question of mine: [one](http://queforum.com/programming-languages-basics/237723-java-jpopupmenu-disappears-mouseentered.html), [two](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/10/jpopupmenu-disappears-on-mouseentered/). Does anyone know is it a robot or human who just cheating for own `SOF` reputation? And is it legal for `SOF` community?

Comment: It all depends, if they provide attribution (including a link back to the original question) then all is well (which I can't find in these examples), if not report it to the team (i'll just find the link)

Comment: There is no link back to original, but as there are no answers, a don't know exactly, are they report back to SOF. I just know that the text of question is copypasted fully.